# Keyboard shortcut for strike-through

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a key shortcut for the "strike through" feature using a Google Doc on a Chromebook? I have tried the ideas already listed from the answers given and they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

> **Chrome OS shortcuts** > Text formatting > **Strikethrough** (**Alt + Shift + 5**)

Source: [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738)